# minimum without the use of lists

Tags: python, class

I was told to make a class that outputs the size, min, max, etc. without using a list and having the attributes mainly be in def add..My attributes are working fine for the most part but for some reason I can't get a minimum. Can anyone give me a quick nudge in the right direction and tell me if I am going down the correct path with this?

```
class Dataset(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.totalScore=0
        self.countScore=0
        self._highest=0
        self._lowest=0
        self.dev=0
        self.mean=0

    def add(self, score):
        self.countScore= self.countScore + 1
        self.totalScore= self.totalScore + score

        self.mean=self.totalScore/self.countScore
        self.dev=self.mean - score


        if score > self._highest:
            self._highest = score
        if score < self._lowest:
            self._lowest = score

    def size(self):
        return(self.countScore)


    def min(self):
        return (self._lowest)


    def max(self):
        return (self._highest)
```

my results is this:

```
This is a program to compute the min, max, mean and
standard deviation for a set of numbers.

Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): 50
Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): 60
Enter a number (<Enter> to quit): 
Summary of 2 scores.
Min: 0
Max: 60.0
Mean: 55.0
Standard Deviation: 7.0710678118654755
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize your initial `self._lowest` to `0` which happens to be lower than all your inputs. Instead, you could try the following:

- initialize it like that: `self._lowest = None`
- in `add`, change the condition to set `self._lowest` to `score` on first call

It would then look like this:

```
if self._lowest is None or score < self._lowest:
  self._lowest = score
```

This way you set `None` as the initial, non-number value meaning *there has been no minimum found yet*. It is then set to the first `score` passed, and updated to the lowest one accordingly on further calls.

Similar issue would happen to your `self._highest` variable for a sequence of inputs that's lower than `0`, i.e. `-9 -1 -5 -3`.

Another alternative, thanks to [@SteveJessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop), is to set `self._lowest` and `self._highest` to `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` respectively. This would reduce your if-statements to:

```
self._lowest = min(self._lowest, score)
self._highest = max(self._highest, score)
```

Comment: Perfectly reasonable. A cheap and cheerful alternative is to initialize the max/min with `float('-inf')` and `float('inf')`. Then there's no need for the special case in this code. The downside is that the result is slightly less useful in the case where `add` is not called at all, i.e. there are no scores.

Comment: @SteveJessop, thanks, didn't think of that. This approach also reduces the if-statements to simple `min`/`max` calls. I've seen `inf` and `-inf` being completely valid initial values for a number of algorithms, so it's just a matter of convention or, in this case, output formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured that was the case, I just didn't know how to go about it. Now I know better.